# only icon on tabs

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm wondering how to suppress the label on the tabs
I want only an icon

```
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Test.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("test").setIndicator("test", 
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_test))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I have an xml file for each tab describing the icon
All works perfectly except I want to have ONLY the icon, not the label

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try using an empty string for the indicator...

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Test.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("test").setIndicator("", 
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_test))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: So how can I force my icon to cover all the tab (fill the blank left by the discarded label)

Comment: @superseed77 I'm not at a computer right now that I can verify but I believe that modifying the `layout_height` of the `TabWidget` will adjust the tab sizes down to fill the space that might have been used for text.. this all depends on the image sizes you use for your tabs.